# Can you change the column length in a view in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Not sure if this is even allowed, but if so, can someone tell me what the T-SQL is?  I've tried the following but to no avail.

```
alter [View_Name]
alter column [Coln_Name] [New size/length] not null
GO
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the length come from the underlying table?

Comment: A view is really nothing more than a named ad-hoc query. If you want to alter the size of a particular field you would need to modified the underlying query. This feels like you're trying to *insert* data to a view?

Comment: What is the motivation for this question?

Answer (score 6):

Not directly.

This is derived automatically from the column expression. You can `CAST` the expression in the View `SELECT` list to a particular datatype though.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to change the column length in the underlying table, or to change the SELECT statement forming the view to CAST or CONVERT the column to a different length data type.

Answer (score 1):

Views are ways to see data in other tables; typically the data is simply whatever is in the underlying table, so you would need to change the column there.

However, you can have views that do things like cast() or convert(); these are typically a bad idea, becuase the data needs to be re-fetched every time the view is used, and these operations add overhead. In the design of the view, you can decide to cast as another data type, or do any transformation you would like - but it has overhead, and will not alter the original data.

If you know what the current view selects, you can use something like:

```
Alter view Viewname[cloumn] as Select cast(original_data as varchar(n)) from Original_Table
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same situation. What I did was:

1. Change the column size in the table that the view looks at.
2. Create a script to recreate the view (if you don't already have one).
3. Delete the view
4. Use the script to recreate the view.

After that the column sizes in the view were the same as the changes I made to the underlying table.

Answer (score 1):

You can not alter the column size in a view as a view is derived from other table. So if you need to change the column size, change the column size of the table. To change the column size use ALTER TABLE as :

ALTER TABLE [Table_Name]

ALTER COLUMN [Column_Name] Data_Type(Size)

After changing the column size you might need to drop the view and recreate it again.

Answer (score 1):

If the length shown in the view doesn't match the underlying table then drop and recreate the view.

Use something like this to investigate the column lengths in the table and view

```
SELECT o.[name], *
FROM sys.all_columns c
INNER JOIN sys.objects o on o.[object_id]=c.[object_id]
WHERE c.[name] = 'OML'
-- AND c.[max_length]=11
ORDER BY O.[name];
```

To get the Drop and Create sql I use SSMS and right click context menu (on the view in the Object Explorer), then go to 'Script View as', and 'DROP And CREATE To'.